# PHP modify array by given date range

Tags: php, arrays, date, filter

I've got a form written in php, with the following array and two variables: 
startDate and endDate.

What I would like to do, is to show the only the dates that are within user-defined date range.

```
$startDate = "2013-03-08";
$endDate = "2013-03-12";

Array
(
    [0] => 2013-03-06|Lorem|Mom|01:45
    [1] => 2013-03-07|ipsum|Dad|01:00
    [2] => 2013-03-08|dolor|Dad|01:45
    [3] => 2013-03-09|sit|Dad|01:00
    [4] => 2013-03-10|amet|Mom|01:45
    [5] => 2013-03-11|Lorem|Mom|01:45
    [6] => 2013-03-12|ipsum|Mom|01:00
    [7] => 2013-03-13|dolor|Dad|01:45
    [8] => 2013-03-14|sit|Mom|01:00
    [9] => 2013-03-15|amet|Mom|01:45
)
```

After posting the form, the array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-03-08|dolor|Dad|01:45
    [1] => 2013-03-09|sit|Dad|01:00
    [2] => 2013-03-10|amet|Mom|01:45
    [3] => 2013-03-11|Lorem|Mom|01:45
    [4] => 2013-03-12|ipsum|Mom|01:00
)
```

What would be the simplest way to make this happen?

Any thoughts?

/janne

Comment: Why do you have multiple values in the same key? Defeats the whole purpose of an array.

Comment: array_filter() would be the obvious function to use

Comment: you could use a foreach and in the foreach you do a substring, transform that substring of the first 10 letters into a timestamd and check wheter the timestamp lies between the user input and then unset the value if it doesn't or like @MarkBaker you use array filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

Let $dates be your input array

```
$dates = array(
           '0' => '2013-03-06|Lorem|Mom|01:45',
           '1' => '2013-03-07|ipsum|Dad|01:00',
           '2' => '2013-03-08|dolor|Dad|01:45',
           '3' => '2013-03-09|sit|Dad|01:00',
           '4' => '2013-03-10|amet|Mom|01:45',
           '5' => '2013-03-11|Lorem|Mom|01:45',
           '6' => '2013-03-12|ipsum|Mom|01:00',
           '7' => '2013-03-13|dolor|Dad|01:45',
           '8' => '2013-03-14|sit|Mom|01:00',
           '9' => '2013-03-15|amet|Mom|01:45)'
        );


$startDate = "2013-03-08";
$endDate = "2013-03-12";

$new_startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$new_endDate = strtotime($endDate);

$user_dates = array();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $date_values = explode('|', $date);
    $current_date_value = $date_values[0];
    $current_date_value = strtotime($current_date_value);

    if ($current_date_value >= $new_startDate && $current_date_value <= $new_endDate) {
        $user_dates[] = $date;
    }
}
```

`$user_dates` will holds the dates you need

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an `array_filter()` function.

```
$startDate = strtotime('2013-03-08');
$endDate = strtotime('2013-03-12');

$array = array(...); // your input array

$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $valArray = explode('|', $value);
    $date = strtotime($valArray[0]);
    return ($date >= $startDate && $date <= $endDate);
});
```

Note that the above is valid for PHP >= 5.3.0 For older versions you would have to replace the anonymous function with a named function and call it like this:

```
$startDate = strtotime('2013-03-08');
$endDate = strtotime('2013-03-12');

$array = array(...); // your input array

$filteredArray = array_filter ($array, 'filterArray');

function filterArray ($value) {
    global $startDate;
    global $endDate;
    $valArray = explode('|', $value);
    $date = strtotime($valArray[0]);
    return ($date >= $startDate && $date <= $endDate);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I asked a similar question and see that this code works, my array though is a json_decoded array which has a key called date. It's actually multiple arrays, what would I change `$valArray = explode('|', $value);` to, to get all my dates from the key `date` thanks. Sample code http://codepad.org/rSJMyMZl

Comment: @Anagio First of all, you would probably pass `$array['results']` to the function, as this is really what you are interested in. Second, you no longer need to use `explode()` in the function, as you already have an array for `$value`.  You simply need to compare on the `$value['date']` value.  See this code sample http://codepad.org/fvPOVBkT Note that I changed from `strtotime()` to `DateTime::createDateFromFormat()` in your case because your dates were not in a format that `strtotime()` can handle.  This doesn't actually work in the codepad as apparently it doesn't have support for DateTime.

Comment: thanks, I just had to update php to 5.3 for `DateTime::createDateFromFormat()` to work. Really appreciate it!!!